# Visa for Indian citizen going to Nepal leaving from the UAE

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, nepal

I'm an Indian passport holder who is in Dubai now, and I need to travel to Nepal for my engagement. Do I need to get a visa or not?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, your citizenship tends to be far more important than your country of residence for such matters.

Answer (score 8):

Indian citizens don't need visa for Nepal and vice versa. Indian citizens can travel to, live in and work in Nepal (some restrictions for government jobs apply) without a visa and vice versa.

Additionally, if you are traveling from India, you can even travel using an Indian voter ID card instead of a passport.